# Can I create table/write into a table in sql server using aws glue?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-serverless

Can I create table/write into a table in sql server using aws glue? I am using pyspark (mssqljdbc) for reading the data, but I don't know how to write into a table.

I can connect to the SQL server, but I am trying to create tables using DDL (other than read/write). Here is
the sample I am using for read.
Please share if anyone have sample code. Thanks

```
df = spark.read.format(i['type']) \
        .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://" + i['host'] + ":" + i['port'] + ";databaseName=" + i['database']) \
        .option("user", i['user']) \
        .option("password", i['password'])\
        .option("dbtable",i['table'])\
        .option("partitionColumn", i['partitioncol']) \
        .option("lowerBound", i['lowerbound']) \
        .option("upperBound", i['upperbound']) \
        .option("numPartitions", i['partitionnum']) \
        .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
        .load()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use normal pyspark code on Glue, but you will need to create a [Glue Connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/connection-using.html), so that you can connect to your SQL server.